# How do I find the distance between two points in a matrix of sequences?

Tags: r, sequence, distance

I have a large matrix that is composed of 0s and 1s. 
I would like to find the distance between 1s.

For example, if I have the first row of a matrix as

```
 0  0  1  0  1  1  0
```

I want the output

```
3  2  1
```

3 is the location of the first 1
2 is the distance between the first and second 1
1 is the location of the second and the third 1

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `which` with `diff`.  Convert the `vector` to logical, find the index where the values are 1 with `which` and get the `diff`erence of index positions

```
i1 <- which(as.logical(v1))
out <- c(i1[1], diff(i1))
out
#[1] 3 2 1
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
```